# Using Http Patch to update certain fields

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, http-verbs

I have the below Employee representation, which resides in a database:

```
public class Employee
{

  int Id {get; set;}

  string Name {get; set;}

  string Position {get; set;}

  string Address {get; set;}

  string EmergencyContact {get; set;}

 }
```

Only the fields Position, Address and EmergencyContact are updatable. Instead of using  PUT, I wanted to implement Patch and only send the updated values in a dictionary.  Are there any downsides to implementing Patch this way as opposed to using Json Patch? Can a simple key-value pair be considered as a formal representation of "[description of changes]"?

Comment: you can also have a look at [this article](https://philsturgeon.uk/api/2016/05/03/put-vs-patch-vs-json-patch/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly valid to use a HTTP Patch and send the key-value pairs that you want to update in the payload as long as the system you are sending to supports that.

The values would have to be the complete value, rather than the add, replace, copy, move operations with just the part that is changing that the JSON Patch requires.

Not all systems support JSON Patch either, so you would have to determine what is supported by the target system.